# cross platform error using jquery getJSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I issue getJSON command against two urls.

```
 $.getJSON(url, myKeyValues, function() {...}
```

One url has a port defined. This call fails with message Cross-Origin Request Blocked. What do I need to change in my getJSON request to acccess an url with a  port number defined? I do not have access to server side code.

Comment: you can't easily - you could setup a proxy that will do it. browsers will block you.

Comment: Investigated. The server application I am using does not seem to handle CORS and suggests reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked` means that you are trying to access another site with your JavaScript. The only working solutuin is to add allow orgin header (well described on [mozilla site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)) on the site you are trying to access.

You can search google also for CORS, because it is exactly what you are trying to do. If you want to test something on your machine you can use chrome extension to disable CORS

Comment: Yes. Read the document before posted. Do you have a working example using jquery  either 
jQuery.getJSON or 
jQuery.ajax()? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: It is completly not related to jQuery. This change must be done in server configuration file like web.config in iis.